# How to use gridView responsively?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application in java, android studio.

For testing I'm using a 10 'tablet and a 7' tablet.

In all screens I used a constraint layout, always avoiding using fixed sizes, to stay responsive.

My problem is in gridView.As you know there is a property

> android:numColumns="4"

Responsible for determining the amount of items horizontally. I can not pass this attribute, because the amount must be the one that fits ... however, if I omit the grid is a single column.

How can I do it?[image]

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvMesas"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/layoutcinza"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pnlTopo">

    </GridView>
```

Comment: you need to set numColumns dynamically?

Comment: @Moises Portillo yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using the code below. So the amount of columns are defined by the available space.

```
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making custom layouts for each screen configuration you want to support.

> You can provide screen-specific layouts by creating additional res/layout/ directories—one for each screen configuration that requires a different layout—and then append a screen configuration qualifier to the layout directory name (such as layout-w600dp for screens that have 600dp of available width).

See https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

If you want to do it by code you do this

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMesas);
gridview.setNumColumns(4);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView#setNumColumns(int)